# Use different pools based on the repository name / Unable to access "Build.Repository.Name" variable in job condition

Tags: azure-pipelines

For my main repository (let's say `rmetzger/flink`), I would like to send Azure Pipelines build jobs to my own pool of agents running very powerful build machines.
For anybody who has forked my repository, I would like to run their build on the build machines provided by Azure.

To achieve that, I believe using [Jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) and [Conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) are the right approach.
I want to define two very similar jobs, each with a condition checking whether the repository is `rmetzger/flink` or not.

This is the relevant part of my `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
jobs:
- job: runOnStrongMachines
  condition: eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'rmetzger/flink')
  pool:
    name: Default
  steps:
  - ...
- job: runOnAzure
  condition: not(eq(variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'rmetzger/flink'))
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - ...
```

Running this, `variables['Build.Repository.Name']` always evaluates to `null`, thus always the second job executes.

I fear that the [predefined `Build.Repository.Name` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is scoped in a way that it is not accessible at this early phase of the build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I fear that the predefined Build.Repository.Name variable is scoped in
>   a way that it is not accessible at this early phase of the build.

YES, correct. `Build.Repository.Name` could not be used at the early phase of build. And also, "the early phase of build" exactly means **job level**. In fact, the [doc link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) you mentioned in the question has announced that **this variable is agent-scoped**:

[image]

As this doc described, this pre-defined variable `Build.Repository.Name` can only be used in script/task level. And in your script, the scope of using this variable in Job condition is job-level instead of agent-level. That's why you receive the `null`.

As work around, you can set the condition in every `step/task` by using this variable `Build.Repository.Name`. Or for convenient,  **add a step at the beginning** to early-exit from the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I'm new to Azure Pipelines, and I could not find any explanation on how exactly "agent scope" is defined. Also, the build repository name is an information that should be available to the machine evaluating the conditions, as it is an information independent of the agent.
That's why I didn't expect this behavior.

Comment: Aha, understood it. Similar with me when I first meet Azure Devops:-) Yes, it is independent of agent. But as you know, the pipeline is running on the agent. Only after the pipeline begin to run, the build repository name can only be get from it. Once the pipeline finished which means the agent job end, these info will not exists in agent any more. This should be easily to understand what is agent-scope. This is as designed, and can not be modified from our backend code. You can use the workaround I offered in answer.

Comment: Thanks. I just confirmed that the workaround from your answer works!

Comment: Welcome:-) Glad hear that.

Comment: When choosing the convenient variant of early-exiting, this job and the entire build will be marked as failed.
Is there any way of working around this? (except for adding a condition to every step?)